# Hide and show other controls based on the drop down value using Orbeon Builder

Tags: orbeon, xforms, xbl

How to create form using Orbeon builder, where user can select value from a drop down and based on the selection the user can see other controls get rendered (probably hidden/shown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, give a meaningful name to that dropdown field; say `gender`.
2. Click on the *Edit Choices* icon for that field, just below the *Control Details* icon, and in the dialog assign meaningful values to each choice. Those are the values you'll refer to in step 3.
3. Finally, in the *Control Details* for the other field, under the *Formulas* tab, if you want that field to only be shown if the value of the `gender` field is `female`, enter the XPath expression `$gender = 'female'`.